# AWS NGINX PHPのセキュリティ全般

Tags: php, aws

EC2とRDSを同VPCで作成しました。

セキュリティグループは各自異なっていて
EC2は80に全てアクセス化、22にMyIPアドレスのみ。
RDSはVPCのアドレス10.0.0.1/24のみにアクセス化。
にしました。これで私のデータベースに接続できるのは同VPS間のみなので、極めて安全でしょうか？

NGINX側では`location / ~ ¥.php$`のみAllow myIP、Deny Allにしました。PHPで生成されたHTMLのみをアクセス可能にしています。この場合、Nginxのエラーログに無いはずの/phpmyadmin/とかに不正アクセスが多発していますが当然アクセス拒否されるので極めて安全でしょうか？

データベースへの接続はMysqlWorkBenchとPHP-PDOにしています。WorkbenchはSSHを通さないといけないのでpemキーなどで制御されるのと、PDOはhttp://hoge.phpのような感じでアクセスできますがPHPファイルへは自分のIPアドレスだけが接続できるので極めて安全ですか？
リバースプロキシ関係で謝ってPHPファイルをキャッシュしてしまいなんてことはありませんか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

曖昧だったり明らかに誤っている記述が複数存在しており、意図や設定内容が文章に正しく反映されているか疑問があります。また、いずれの質問についても

- 想定する攻撃シナリオ
- それに対する対策方法
- それを実現する具体的な設定

のどれかに不明確な点があります。これらが明確になってないと、トンチンカンで無意味な「対策」になっていたり、考慮漏れによりわかりやすい大穴が残っていたりすることがままあります。

したがって、安全かどうかの判断はできません。

「極めて」という修飾が何を比較対象としているのかについても明確になっておらず、一般的に想定されるセキュリティレベルより遙かに高いことを意図しているとも考えられ、なおさら安易に判断できません。

Answer (score 1):

極めて安全の定義が曖昧ですが・・・。

それなりに対策がされているかと思いますが、まだまだ心配なようでしたら、PHPファイルにも認証処理を入れれば良いかと思います。

あとは、閲覧用のドメインと、更新に使うPHPを呼び出すドメインを分けて設定も分け、PHP側の設定でもIPアドレス判定を入れるとか、やり出すとキリが無いので、何かあった場合にすぐに気がつける監視体制を整えた方がいいかもしれません。
異常な負荷や、普段より多いプロセス数などを監視しておくことで、逆にシステムが停止してしまった場合などの検知にも使えます。

対策方法が思いつかずに、心配なら専門家に頼んだ方がいいです。